# PHP sending a reply back in XML

Tags: php, xml

I am fairly new to php so be kind.

I am receiving an XML file from a client that I am parsing to a database. I have this part down but my problem is I want to send a reply back in XML. I am trying to test on my local machine and it is not working. Here is my code:

```
<?php
//create and send XML confirmation

    $replyXML = '<Order><Action>UPDATE</Action><OrderType>DEPOT</OrderType><Message>UPDATE</Message><OrderNumber>'.$orderNumber.'</OrderNumber><OrderId>'.$orderID.'</OrderId><OrderCreatedDate>'.$orderCreatedDate.'</OrderCreatedDate><StoreNumber>'.$storeNumber.'</StoreNumber><OrderDetails><OrderDetail><OrderDetailId>'.$orderDetailID.'</OrderDetailId><OrderDetailStatus>'.$orderDetailStatus.'</OrderDetailStatus><OrderDetailCreatedDate>'.$orderDetailCreatedDate.'</OrderDetailCreatedDate><SKUData><SKUNumber>'.$skuNumber.'</SKUNumber><SKUDescription>'.$skuDescription.'</SKUDescription><SKUMessage>'.$skuMessage.'</SKUMessage></SKUData></OrderDetail></OrderDetails></Order>';



$URL = "http://localhost:8888/staples/reply";

        $ch = curl_init($URL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$replyXML");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

When I go to the "reply" directory on my machine nothing is there.

Please let me know where I have gone wrong.

Comment: It's a little unclear exactly what the problem is. Do you mean the reply directory on your filesystem? Or in the browser? If the filesystem, this code wouldn't be creating new files. That'd be up to whatever script it's posting to.

Comment: Is that a valid xml?if it's not you can't..And I see php variables in it..

Comment: what does it display when you `echo $output;` ?

Answer (score 0):

You're treating your variable `$replyXML` as a string. Remove the double quotes so it pulls your XML in

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $replyXML);
```

Comment: That's not actually going to make any difference. Since `$replyXML` is already a string,  `"$replyXML"` just takes that string, puts it into a string, and returns that. Although yes, it'd be better to remove the unnecessary quotes anyway.